# PDFTron version 7 to version 10 migration is breaking existing functionality

Tags: objective-c, pdf, pdftron

[image]

PDFtron version 7 to version 10 migration is producing the error mentioned above.

How to resolve this error and how to retain existing functionality?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read each migration guide to see where it's stated: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/upgrade/

Comment: WHat is `PTAnnotationViewController`, I guess it inherits from some PDFTronSDK ViewController, right? Which one? PSPDFNoteAnnotationViewController

Comment: @Larme : It's PDFTron not a pspdfkit

Comment: Sorry, since PDFTron has been bought by Apprise, I mistook it. Check there the change notes: https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/ios/changelog/v8-0-0-76251/ but the logic is the same, maybe it's stated there since it seems to be a big change. But maybe you could also check what are now the `init` method available for `PTAnnoticationViewCOntroller`...

Comment: From seeing quickly the doc, it seems you can init the PTAnnotationVC with PTAnnotation Manager, and the PTAnnotationManager with a `PDFViewCtrl`. Might a clue to dig...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, updating from version 7 to the latest version 10 will require going through each of the changelogs between your previous version and new version. It depends on which exact version you are migrating from, but you could start by looking at version [7.0.1](https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/ios/changelog/v7-0-1-72288/) and then all the way up to [10.0.0](https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/ios/changelog/v10-0-0/).

For your case specifically, you should look at the [PTDocumentController](https://docs.apryse.com/api/ios/Classes/PTDocumentController.html) class as it provides a drop-in viewer component that handles all of the UI setup and management (and therefore also already handles most API changes between versions for you). This is the recommended approach for the majority of use cases and projects.